# Can't convert json to [String: Any] in swift

Tags: json, swift

I used the "let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers)" function to parse my json. I then printed it. It gave me:

```
 (
        {
        id = 30;
        name = name1;
    }
)
```

Then I tried converting my json using 
`as? [String: Any]`. But when I printed it it gave me nil.
Why did it give me nil? 
Help would really be appreciated.

Comment: Please read the output. The parentheses `()` indicate clearly that the object is an array, it's `[[String: Any]]`. And why `.mutableContainers`? You assign the result to an **im**mutable constant.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Your JSON object root: is Array Of Dictionaries
/*
    (
        {
        id = 30;
        name = name1;
        }
    )
*/



    if let arrayOfDict = jsonWithObjectRoot as? [[String: Any]] {
           for dict in arrayOfDict{
               print(dict["name"])
            }
        }
```